# How to use aggregate to count the documents

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a documents like :

```
{ uid:2, tid: 100 },
{ uid:2, tid: 100 },
{ uid:2, tid: 103 }, 
{ uid:3, tid: 103 }, 
{ uid:3, tid: 100 }, 
{ uid:3, tid: 100 },
{ uid:8, tid: 103, total: 1 }
```

I want to statistics the count of same uid and tid

```
{ uid: 2, tid: 100, total: 2},
{ uid: 2, tid: 103, total: 1},
{ uid: 3, tid: 100, total: 2},
{ uid: 3, tid: 103, total: 1 }
```

I have try to use

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { $match: { uid: { $in: [ "2", "3" ] } } },
    { $group: { _id: "$tid", total: { $sum: 1 } } },
    { $sort: { total: -1 } }
])
```

then I get the data like

```
{
    "result" : [ 
          {
              "_id" : "100",
              "uid" : "2",
              "total" : 2.0000000000000000
          }, 
          {
              "_id" : "103",
              "student" : "2",
              "total" : 1.0000000000000000
          }
      ],
      "ok" : 1.0000000000000000 }
```

some data are not shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to count total of `total` fields the correct aggregation would be:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { $match: { uid: { $in: ["2","3"] } } },
    { $group: { 
        _id: { tid: "$tid", uid: "$uid" }, 
        total: { $sum: "$total" } 
        } 
    },
    { $sort: { total: -1 } }
])
```

That will filter collection by `uid` then count sum of all `total` fields grouped by `tid` and `uid` and sort it backwards bu `total`.